# Mating with B+N+handicap

Tags: endgame, chess-variants

Elsewhere there was a discussion on "pass chess" (instead of making a move you can pass...if you don't happen to stand in check!). There are three sensible rule variants of pass chess:

- on/off: Anyone can pass anytime.
- tis/tisn: Anyone who has the "pass token" may pass and after that hands over the token.
- ko: You may not pass if the opponent just passed in the preceding turn.

The stalemate rule possibly would be more logical with the one in James' comment (you must pass out of stalemate) but way then we agreed on "stalemate ends the game, no passing either" (otherwise, B+N should be easily won even in the wrong corner - White stalemates with K+B and regroups the N).

KQ/K is always won. The last variant seems to be the most interesting (KR/K is won with a lot of trickery). The key to win many endgames in this variant is checking the opponent and then pass, so no weaseling out of zugzwang by passing! We couldn't agree on whether KBN/K was won, which relies heavily on non-checking zugzwang.

Is ko-pass KBN/K won? Watertight algorithm please!

Comment: What is the stalemate rule? I suppose that if I put the opponent in stalemate, other than by passing, then they must pass and the game continues? And if I put them in stalemate by passing, then the game is drawn?

Comment: In your ko-pass variant, by "the opponent just passed", do you mean "the opponent passed on the previous turn"? (I'm going by the idea of ko in go.)

Comment: @RosieF: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @JamesMartin: Omission by me. See edit.